# AspNet-Contrib only works on a new project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnet-contrib

I have a ready-made project, and in it, when connecting authentication via Google, the connection does not work. All the standard settings described in the example. But if I create a new project, then everything works for me. What could be the problem? I can provide the necessary code

**UPD**

AccountController.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn(string provider)
    {
        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/Register" }, provider);
    }
```

And Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/signin";
            options.LogoutPath = "/signout";
        })
        .AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = "myId";
            options.ClientSecret = "MySecret";
        });
```

I found a problem, if you finish this code then authorization does not occur

```
services.AddDbContext<MainContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MainConnection")),
                ServiceLifetime.Transient);
        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
                 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MainContext>()
                 .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: provide the code that you've tried, as well as the problem that you ran into (Eg what does "the conection does not work" mean).

Comment: @sbkrogers idk what other information to provide to me. Above, I added the code, but as I wrote, it is the same as [link](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/tree/dev/samples/Mvc.Client) I go to the authentication page google but does not return the Claims and cookie